# How to create static library with XCode4.2?

Tags: ios, xcode, static

I'm trying to create static library which named "testlib"
 with Xcode4.2.
there is no way to new a "testlib.a"(always red color).
could anybody give me detail-step?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you  need:
Actually, XCode created it. For the device target, it will not be red. For the Simulator, it is always red.
Go to this path and get what you need: /Users/"username"/Library/Developer/Xcode/ProjectName/....

Comment: thanks a ton! Finally,I view the testlib.a through Terminal. Angrily,the path is very very very...  just like below:   /Users/"username"/Library/Developer/Xcode/deriveddata/libTest-arczezkfogufbnghclivygklfcln/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/testlib.a